# How to design a bell nozzle from scratch

Tags: rockets, nozzle

I need help creating my own custom model rocket nozzle. I'm making a model rocket, it will have many intricate parts, but the most intricate maybe the nozzle. My question is where do I start if I want to create my own custom rocket nozzles. I have specifically chosen the bell nozzle that is widely used. Though I don't know how to make the blueprints with the specifications. Hence are there any sites, books, journals that outline how am I able to do so? Or are there any example that I can modify to my liking?

Comment: Try Sutton’s *Rocket Propulsion Elements*.

Comment: In the 1970s we were taught how to design nozzles using the method of characteristics (a graphical method).  I was curious enough to see if this was still in use.  It may be, according to this 2013 paper (albeit with help from Matlab). https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281029694_Design_of_a_Supersonic_Nozzle_using_Method_of_Characteristics and this 2010 paper http://jjmie.hu.edu.jo/files/v4n3/103-08%20done.pdf

Comment: @OrganicMarble I read it and it says its for 2d nozzles: " In this paper, a method based on the theory of characteristics is presented for two dimensional,supersonic nozzle design."

Comment: An excellent starting point!

Comment: @OrganicMarble i was hoping for a 3d

Answer (score 2):

It is an interesting question and I am afraid there is no simple answer to this question as there are many variables in it, for starters design will change with the chamber pressure, fuel used, flume profile needed, exit velocity. Make sure you make a proper design as nozzles can blast from the throat.

Basics of designing CONDI nozzle can be found here:
https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/nozzled.html
Another tool that will help you could be:
http://www.engapplets.vt.edu/fluids/CDnozzle/cdinfo.html

I know this is brief but this could be a starting point.

Comment: A good stackexchange answer will include at least a short summary of the material in the link. Link-only answers are discouraged. Can you include at least an outline of what the OP needs to consider before designing a nozzle? There must be some information necessary, mass flow rate, pressures, temperatures... It might be good to point out that *one should know a lot about the engine first, before* thinking about designing a nozzle.

Comment: What does this mean --> "Make sure you make a proper design as nozzles can blast from the throat."

Comment: Once we eyeballed a CONDI design for sugar rocket and it blasted with some analysis and study we found that the combustion chamber pressure was too much to handle for the nozzle and it was an only specific case for our nozzle and it broke from the throat/where CON and DI part meets.